# Horizontal scrolling in Safari on one content type only when logged out?

Tags: 7

So I have spent numerous hours trying to solve the following issue and without success I bring it to Drupal Answers. For some reason, on my site for content type 'level_1' when browsing in Safari it creates long horizontal scrolling. The strange thing is that when you are logged in, the issue is not there. Furthermore the issue doesn't exist when I coded the HTML/CSS pre-Drupal installation.

It's not an issue of caching as I've made changes and checked they followed through when not logged in.

Anyone have any ideas?

If someone has the opportunity to try and debug this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

The error occurs here in the Safari browser:
http://beta.innovista.org/about-us

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking though the markup, the problem is on the H2 for your search form.

`<h2 class="element-invisible">Search form</h2>`

Can't say exactly what's up, but if you take off the `width` from `.level1 h2, .related h2, .tabTog h2` then it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing a link.  The problem also occurs in Chrome, but not Firefox.  I'm pretty sure your problem is in the iframe that sits outside the "widewrap" container.  It is the only thing that stretches across the screen on inspection.

I'm guessing it is part of some facebook (body class:fbBody, table id:fbChrome) integration tool - there is a table inside the iframe that is pulling the width across the screen.

Comment: Hey @phil-owen it doesn't seem to be the Facebook div as you are suggesting because this is also on other page (such as home) and the issue doesn't occur here. Also I tried removing the Facebook div and it doesn't resolve the issue:/ What did you use to inspect the site by the way? Any more ideas?

Comment: I'm just using the developer tools (inspect element) in the Chrome browser.  Opened all the html elements and scrolled down with my cursor to see dimensions & margins and whether something spans the empty body space to the right of the page.  I missed the h2 heading that Chapabu mentioned above.  He's right, eliminating the "87.01298%" width on those classes fixes the problem.